# Compare two date fields in ACCESS

Tags: microsoft-access

In MS Access 2013, if you have two short date fields, a and b how, to make a validation rule such that, `b >=a` ? i tried `>= 'a'` didn't work so i want to make sure that date b is never less than date a.

Comment: Kinda left us with little to go on. Are `a` and `b` form or table fields? How are you making the validation; in the table settings, in VBA, a query, what?

Comment: @CharlieRB table fields, no vba, or any programming language, i'm using queries

Comment: Can you screen shot the query so we can see what you are working with?

Comment: @CharlieRB I'm using the query provided in the answer below for now, testing it

Comment: @CharlieRB I don't think it will work cause it's a select statement, I want to restrict input, not do searches

Comment: Correct. Queries are used to search for data. If you are using forms for data entry, you can restrict it by comparing the form fields.

Comment: @CharlieRB I'll be using access form fields, so please let me know how

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a Access teaching site, so you need to look up "validate Access form fields" to learn how to do it. It isn't hard. When you have done it, update this question if you have problems and we can help you from there.

Answer (score 1):

You will need use Access SQL language to generate this validation.

For instance

```
SELECT IIF ( b >= a, b, a) AS TheBiggerDate FROM Table
```

Good Luck.

Comment: tried it, the thing is I want to not let the user input b if it's > a, I don't want to search